# Laravel DomPDF Google fonts not loading

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Trying to use Google Fonts with Laravel DomPDF 0.7.* but I'm having a hard time getting them to show. In fact I can't get any custom fonts to work, not just Google Fonts.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">

            .signature {
                font-family: 'Caveat', cursive !important;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="signature">Name</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what shows up, it's supposed to be a handwriting font.

[image]

In `dompdf.php` config file, the font dir and font cache are both writeable.

```
"DOMPDF_FONT_DIR" => storage_path('app/tmp/'), 
"DOMPDF_FONT_CACHE" => storage_path('app/tmp/'),
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public function download(Request $request, string $contractKey)
{
    $item = Item::findOrFail($contractKey);

    $body = @$item->contract;

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.contract', [
        'body'  => $this->cleanContract($body),
        'docId' => md5($item->id),
        'item'  => $item,
        'ip'    => $ip = @$request->ips()[1] ?: $request->ip(),
    ]);

    $pdf->output();
    $dom_pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();

    $canvas = $dom_pdf->get_canvas();
    $canvas->page_text($canvas->get_width() - 70, $canvas->get_height() - 30, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, [0, 0, 0]);


    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: Please try this `letter-spacing: 1px;` at `.signature` CSS

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn it's not the right font, the letter spacing isn't the issue

Comment: You could try updating to the latest version and see if that fixes it. The current version is `0.8.0`

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Comment: @whoacowboy added it

Comment: @Wasim I updated my answer, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

## Font Location Answer

I have only been able to get this to work by having the fonts on my server.

You need to tell DomPDF where the fonts are.

```
public function download(Request $request, string $contractKey)
{
    $item = Item::findOrFail($contractKey);

    $body = @$item->contract;

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.contract', [
        'body'  => $this->cleanContract($body),
        'docId' => md5($item->id),
        'item'  => $item,
        'ip'    => $ip = @$request->ips()[1] ?: $request->ip(),
    ]);

    $pdf->output();
    $dom_pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();

    // set font dir here
    $dom_pdf->set_option('font_dir', storage_path('fonts/'));

    $canvas = $dom_pdf->get_canvas();
    $canvas->page_text(
        $canvas->get_width() - 70, 
        $canvas->get_height() - 30, 
        "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, [0, 0, 0]);    
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Download fonts to `storage/fonts`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">

            .signature {
                font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="signature">Name</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I use [DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to integrate it with Laravel. It is a lot easier.

## Typo Answer

You need to remove the `!important` from `'Caveat', cursive; !important;` see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tg3e4d69/). There is an extra semicolon.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">

            .signature {
                font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="signature">Name</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why the syntax error was there but that's not the problem either. Same issue.